# Why isn't my .innerHTML working in sublime text 3?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn Javascript but for some reason my .innerHTML isnt working. It doesnt even look like its registering within Sublime Text (not changing colors). Any help would be great.

```
<body>

    <div id="container">

        <h1>Internal &amp; External Javascript</h1>
        <p id="output"></p>

    </div> <!-- #Container -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementbyId("output").innerHTML = "This text was created with internal Javascript";

    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I didn't make the B in by uppercase. Sorry for the easy question, remember, I am new to this.